# Annotate Java Objects with SOAP Headers

Tags: java, spring, soap, jaxb, wsdl

I am building a client for a SOAP 1.1 webservice.  I am using the spring WebServiceTemplate to send the requests.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <qualifier value="v60WebServiceTemplate"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="ncctMessageFactory"/>
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
            <property name="httpClient" ref="trustAllHttpClient" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="ncctV6Marshaller"/>
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="ncctV6Marshaller"/>
</bean>
```

I am using jax2-maven-plugin to generate annotated java objects from an xsd.  I also have a wsdl, but it isn't configured in my .xjb file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
          jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="NCCT_v60.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:simple/>
        </jxb:globalBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I send it with the  Spring web service template class like this.  I have to manually add the SOAPAction header (which I would rather not do).

```
private ServiceResponse makeNcctV6Request(ServiceRequest request, String uri, String soapAction) {
    request.setVersion(ncctServiceVersion);
    return (ServiceResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(uri, request, createCallback(soapAction));
}

private SoapActionCallback createCallback(final String soapAction) {

    return new SoapActionCallback(soapAction) {
        public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) {
            SaajSoapMessage soapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
            MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = soapMessage.getSaajMessage().getMimeHeaders();
            mimeHeaders.setHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);
        }
    };
}
```

When I call this function, I have to hardcode the soap action when it is right there in the wsdl.  Is there a way that I can configure jaxb2-maven to use the WSDL to add an annotation that I can use? Or some other way that I can get this directly from the WSDL?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you overriding the `doWtithMessage` of the `SoapActionCallback`? You are basically reimplementing the existing functionality. You can create it once and simply reuse it or just pass it into your method (new `SoapActionCallback(soapAction)`. There isn't another way of doing this in Spring WS.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your suggestion.  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What isn't understandable, you are basically overridding the default implementation why I wonder. The only thing you should need is `new SoapActionCallback(soapAction);` and be done.